# How do I open Wine again!

Tags: wine, steam

Sigh...so this might be a stupid question. I'm learning my way around Ubuntu (been bottle feed on windows my whole life). I figured out how to install wine, then steam, then installed Skyrim. This took me all night. So when Skyrim froze before opening, I kinda shutdown the computer and called it a night.

Now i am up and ready to tackle this thing, but i can't seem to find, or figure out how to open Skyrim again. I'm not sure if i need to open steam again, or if i can go straight to Skyrim. but each one i downloaded popped up a window on its own when it was finished installing in the terminal. so i have no clue how to get to it.

I did however open wine tricks through the (search your computer and online resources) button. and steam does show up, but i don't know what to do from there. i found a skyrim exe, but when i click on it it says it can't open the archive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply running `wine /path/to/skyrim.exe` should open Skyrim using Wine.

As pointed out in the comments you can go the extra mile and put this in a fule named `Skyrim.desktop` on your desktop:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Skyrim
Exec=wine /path/to/skyrim.exe
Icon=some-icon
Type=Application
Categories=GTK;GNOME;Wine;Game
```

If this fixed your problem/answered the question please click the check mark between the ^ and v on my answer!

Comment: It should be put into a script so that he just needs to execute the script.

Comment: Ok I'll work on a desktop file now!

Comment: ok so wine /path/to/skyrim.exe? sorry If I sound stupid, but can you give an example? do you mean to actually type in "wine /path/to/skyrim.exe" or should i input something in between the back slashes?

Comment: yes, or you could do `wine 'C:\Program Files\Skyrim\Skyrim.exe'` (If that is where `Skyrim.exe` is.

Comment: ok well there must be something wrong with the way I downloaded it. Because it wont let me open any file in wine.

Comment: Sorry i didnt understand properly :) replqfe /path/to/skyrim.exe qith the path to skyrim.exe